# How to check the variables passing through the model class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a code as the following:

```py
# models.py

class UserFollower(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user_id} follows {self.following_user_id}"
```

Now here, I want to check when the data is passed, if the `user_id` equals the `following_user_id`, it will output a message saying "It isn't possible" and not save the model. Of course later in the development, I wouldn't have the "Follow" button or something like that associated with the same user, but in this case, how would I do so?? Or is it something I can't do in the `models.py` and do it in the `views.py`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/| https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints

Comment: I think I referred to the wrong word... not specifically the 'constraint' defined in the Django model but I mean like a 'condition' where I can maybe write something like `if A: B... else: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

```
class UserFollower(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def clean(self):
        if user_id_id == following_user_id_id:
            raise ValidationError("User ID is the same as following_user")
```

Btw, you foreign key should not have the *_id* prefix. When you ask for a foreign key field of a model, you get an instance of the linked model.
If you add *_id* to the name of the field, you get the id of the linked instance. (this is why I put *_id_id* on the example fields).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    linked_item = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, ...)


foo = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
foo.linked_item  # is an instance of OtherModel
foo.linked_iutm_id  # is an integer
```